# Mark/search a word in closed folding

Tags: search, notepad++, folding

In Notepad++, when all my foldings (created by using "define language as") are close, then the search and mark functions don't look into the hidden text.

Is there a way to make these functions look into the hidden text (instead of having to open all folding with Alt+1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a 'Find all in current document' it will show you the results in a new pane on the bottom side. Perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working the search/mark function open the folding.It was a mistake I checked "Macth whole word only".